# In tmux, is it possible to list all panes in all windows?

Tags: tmux

Say, I got two windows, Window 1 contains 2 pane (1, 2), Window 2 contains 3 panes(1,2,3), and I'm in pane 1 in Window 1, and I want to jump directly into the pane 2 in Window 2, `PREFIX w` which is `choose-window` will list all the windows in the session so I can jump into the right window, but it will not list the panes, `PREFIX q` which is `display-panes` will let me choose the right pane only in the current window, but not across windows.

So I wonder if there is any command that let me choose panes across windows.
The best solution is `choose-window` or a new command will not only list all the windows but also list all the panes inside each window like `tree` in a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old post, actually this problems was already solved by commit [aad4e4d](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/aad4e4ddb194cba9c01b0ddd696fb7b214e1a7eb) on github page a long ago, use `choose-tree` (just bind it to a key) to show all panes in all sessions/widows/tabs, it even shows a preview box when you scroll line into one pane from the list, very nice.

Just compile and install `tmux` from github source code and you can use this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this quite easily by adding a binding or changing the binding of `PREFIX s choose-session` to something like `PREFIX s choose-tree`. Or you could bind this to a new shortcut like `PREFIX t choose-tree` since `t` currently just shows a clock that I haven't found a use for.

You can then use the arrow keys to navigate this tree or map `h` and `l` in vi-choice mode to expand/close the tree.

This does require a certain version of tmux (1.8 or higher I think).

EDIT: There is actually an even faster way to do it than a fuzzy search. Add `-u` to the end of the choose-tree mapping and you can select a session with a single letter (listed on the left side of the screen). This is faster than pretty much ANY fuzzy search, because it only requires a key or chord (PREFIX) a shortcut (t) and then a session selection (a-z).

This has just vastly improved my session switching, thanks for the question, and let me know if you still want to do a fuzzy match.

Comment: Did you try it yourself? It doesn't work like that.

Comment: This has also been asked and partially answered on reddit, https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/3ceq8o/tmux_speed_switch/ and overall it seems like if you have a HUGE number of sessions, then you may need a better search, like the tmux-sessionist plugin for that. https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sessionist
Or you could hack a shell command like this guy,
http://brettterpstra.com/2014/05/11/making-my-tmux-life-easier/